# PostgreSQL how to write trigger

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a following table like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU3gh.png
where sid stands for sailor ID, and bid stands for boat ID.

I want to write a trigger and a function to detect whether the new input is invalid. Look at the table, the 3rd record shouldn't be there because the renting time has overlap with the former one, one boat can't be rented before it is returned. That is to say, I want a trigger and a function to stop input like the 3rd one, when someone tries to give a 3rd input, it will just stop you from doing so.

Currently I wrote the following code, but as I am new to this, I am really not sure whether it is correct:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $logupdate$ 
DECLARE
judge boolean;
BEGIN 
judge := EXECUTE ( 'SELECT starttime,endtime,NEW.starttime,NEW.endtime FROM reserves WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND startdate = NEW.startdate AND (starttime,endtime) overlaps(NEW.starttime,NEW.endtime) IS NULL'); 
IF judge = f THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'failed due to some reasons'; 
END IF;
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$logupdate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logupdate 
before UPDATE ON reserves 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update();
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: You don't need a trigger for this. You can use an exclusion constraint: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Comment: I use this as a practice of trigger, and I really wonder why the trigger is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. consider using a timestamp field instead of seperate date and time fields for simplicity.  you can easily format a timestamp into either a date or time.
2. update and insert triggers must return NEW on success, or FALSE/NULL
3. in order to enforce a constraint with a trigger you must run a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, otherwise the row's already added.

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER logupdate 
   BEFORE UPDATE ON reserves 
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update();

   CREATE FUNCTION update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
     minstart :=  EXECUTE ( 'SELECT MAX(endtime) FROM reserves WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND startdate = NEW.startdate' )   ;
     IF minstart < NEW.starttime THEN RETURN FALSE;
     RETURN NEW;
   END
   $$
   ```

Comment: whenever I insert a wrong input, it still is inserted which shouldn't happen.

Comment: please see the top, i have made the updated code there

Comment: You don't need the `execute()` you can simply use `SELECT MAX(endtime)  into minstart FROM reserves WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND startdate = NEW.startdate`

Comment: Thx horse, I have tried your way, but it still allows the wrong input.

Comment: And i have made an improvement of the judgement of overlapping time. I used the overlaps method instead of  subtracting two time to see whether its a positive or negative. Because the latter one has problem in it. Please see my new code at the very top.